# Can someone explain the FORM and LABEL tag in HTML to me?

Tags: html

I don't see myself as very good at HTML yet, so can someone explain the FORM and LABEL tag in HTML?

I appreciate all answers, thank you!

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Forms/Your_first_HTML_form

Comment: [https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_form.asp](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_form.asp) and [https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_label.asp](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_label.asp)

Comment: You can find any information according your requests on MDN resources: 
1) https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form
2) https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label

Answer (score -1):

Did you try to search online for explanations? W3schools is a good place to learn.

FORM:
https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_form.asp

The  tag is used to create an HTML form for user input.

The  element can contain one or more form elements.

LABEL:
https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_label.asp

The  tag defines a label for an  element.

The  element does not render as anything special for the user. However, it provides a usability improvement for mouse users, because if the user clicks on the text within the  element, it toggles the control.

The for attribute of the  tag should be equal to the id attribute of the related element to bind them together.